# Unreal Engine 4 Building Error: Unknow platform for action trying to compile dte80a.cpp

Tags: c++, windows, unreal-engine4

```
Building UE4Editor and ShaderCompileWorker...
 
Using 
Visual Studio 2019 14.28.29913 toolchain (C:\msvs\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910) 
and Windows 10.0.18362.0 SDK (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10).
 
Unknown platform for action: command 'C:\msvs\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe', 
arguments 
'"H:\ProjectA\Engine\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\VisualStudioDTE\dte80a.cpp" 
/c /nologo /Fo "H:\ProjectA\Engine\Engine\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\VisualStudioDTE\dte80a.obj"
/I . 
/I C:\msvs\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\INCLUDE 
/I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" 
/I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" 
/I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" 
/I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" 
/I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt"'
 
C:\msvs\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(45,5): 
error MSB3073: 
The command
"..\..\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat 
-Target="UE4Editor Win64 Development" 
-Target="ShaderCompileWorker Win64 Development -Quiet" -WaitMutex -FromMsBuild" 
exited with code 6.
```

An error occurred while building UE4 Engine (UE4Editor and ShaderCompileWorker) from source code.
I have tried clean and rebuild quite many times. Seems not helping.
How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Unknown platform for action: command is the key.
Find this string in your solution. You will find it in unrealBuildTool.
And set breakpoint at the line.
The issue maybe is the parseActionPlatform make mistake. And find out the reason.
Maybe is your action.commandPath.fullname contains condition is fail. Try to fix it.
Maybe this answer will be deleted again. But I don't care. Because I fix the same issue use these two solution.